# How to get React to Stop watching the state of a parent object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I guys I have an obj I pull from a server and set into state responses. the object has an array of obj's that I pull out and set to a different state variable. If I change someone in the state of the obj I pulled out it, changes the state of it's original parent obj. How to I prevent this so the user can choose to save it into the parent? here's what I'm doing.

```
    const [responses, setResponses] = React.useState();
    const [editedComponent, setEditedComponent] = React.useState({
    name: '',
    things: [],}); 

const handleChangeSelectComponent = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.value;


    setEditedComponent(responses.find((response) => response.name === name));
  };

const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { id, value } = e.target;

    const index = parseInt(id);

    const obj = { ...editedComponent };
    obj.things[index].whatsWrong = value;

    setEditedComponent(obj);
  };
```

I just want to be able to edit editedComponent, then choose if it gets saved into responses. any help would be much appreciated. It's nice having them both in state but thinking I might have to pull one out?

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't clear enough, the state variables (responses and editedComponent) are confusing. Also you're changing the shape of your state variables' content (well at least editedComponent). It goes from being `{ name: string, responses: Response[] }` initially to `Response` in `handleChangeSelectComponent`.

Comment: yeah I need other names for this to make sense will edit but. responses gets loaded with and array like this [{name: example, responses: [{item},{item}]},{name: anotherExample, responses:[{item},{item}]}. then I pull one of those objects out and save in editedComponet, then edit the {item} in editedComponet,  but it changes the state of responses also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably thinking that this lines copies your editedComponent:

```js
const obj = { ...editedComponent };
// but this is actually equivalent to
//   const obj = {}
//   obj.name = editedComponent.name
//   obj.things = editedComponent.things
// so here, obj.things === editedComponent.things :(
```

But it is only copying the OUTER object, not the INNER `things` array. Therefore when you do:

```js
obj.things[index].whatsWrong = value;
```

You're actually modifying your the same array that is also in `responses`.

If you want to modify a nested property in a object, you need to clone the full object, otherwise you'll be modifying your original data. Here is one way to solve your issue:

```js
const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(editedComponent))
```

But you can also look for a `clone(object)` function on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=clone).